# apigatewayv2-controller and HTTP headers management

Tags: kubernetes, aws-api-gateway

I try to manage my AWS HTTP API gateway and its resources by the controller. I got a confusion due to manipulation by the HTTP header.

I need to overwrite the header `Host: my.local.host`.

I use `Integration` manifest to manage it:

```yaml
apiVersion: apigatewayv2.services.k8s.aws/v1alpha1
kind: Integration
metadata:
  name: integration-my
  namespace: rental-connect
spec:
  apiRef:
    from:
      name: adopt-api-gateway-my
  connectionID: id
  integrationType: HTTP_PROXY
  connectionType: VPC_LINK
  integrationURI: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:...
  integrationMethod: ANY
  payloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
  requestParameters: <here I need help>
```

I suppose `requestParameters` can help me. But I have absolutely no idea in what format I can use it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

```
apiVersion: apigatewayv2.services.k8s.aws/v1alpha1
kind: Integration
metadata:
  name: integration-my
  namespace: rental-connect
spec:
  apiRef:
    from:
      name: adopt-api-gateway-my
  connectionID: id
  integrationType: HTTP_PROXY
  connectionType: VPC_LINK
  integrationURI: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:...
  integrationMethod: ANY
  payloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
  requestParameters: {"overwrite:header.Host": "my.hostname.com"}
```